# ecrypftfs - strange non-deterministic behavior

Tags: ecryptfs

I have two sets of folders:

- plaintextA, ecryptfsA
- plaintextB, ecryptfsB

They are mounted from fstab. I have a single set of parameters in /root/.ecryptfsrc (actually I have no idea if there is a way mount from fstab with multiple parameter sets) - so both use the same password. "mount" also shows them with the same ecryptfs_sig. I do not use filename encryption.

What I tried is this:

- Create a file in plaintextA
- Take the corresponding file from ecryptfsA and move it to ecryptfsB
- See if plaintextB contains my original file

The surprising result is this: It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

If it does not work, the resulting plaintext file shows up as 0 bytes and trying to access it results in "No such file or directory".

My impression is that the result depends on the filename (testfile.tst repeatedly did not work, while testfile.txt worked).

Is there any logical explanation for this?

Comment: I can not tell what you are doing =)

Comment: Just FYI, encryption must be non-deterministic in order to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using it wrong.

I don't think eCryptFS folders are designed to be manipulated by the encrypted files like that, the main interface should be through the mounted plaintext folder. It's probably never been tested, and buggy results will probably never be fixed.

So, don't do that?

But anyway, did you try

- unmounting & re-mounting after manipulating the encrypted files? May at least result in more consistent behavior.
- If you're calling `mount` or `mount.ecryptfs` directly you can try the verbose command:

  > verbose
  >               Log  ecryptfs  information  to /var/log/messages.  Do not run eCryptfs in verbose-mode unless you are doing so for the sole purpose of  development,  since
  >             secret values will be written out to the system log in that case.

Comment: I am trying to figure out, if ecryptfs is usable for my backup solution. In case that my machine breaks, I will have to decrypt the files somewhere else. So I thing this use-case is not as esoteric as it may seem.
Your other comment was helpful. Unmounting and re-mounting fixes the broken file.
Still I would really like to know what is going on and ecryptfs seems to be lacking logfiles etc. that could give me a hint.

Comment: I wouldn't use eCryptFS to make backups, it has config files separate from the encrypted files, and there are plenty of questions by people trying to recover their files from eCryptFS backups (sometimes unsuccessfully). It *should* work as a backup though, in theory. I'd still pick a more self-contained tool like gpg (of a tar.gz for example) or luks.